# How can I integrate unit tests that "break" the existing master branch?

Tags: unit-testing, version-control, travis-ci

This is an issue that's happened to me in the past few months. The master branch of a repository I contribute to has several functions that are not implemented according to specification; that is, if there were more/correct unit tests, they would demonstrate that the current master build is broken. However, without those tests, the build passes.

Of course, the ideal thing to do is to fix the functions and submit a pull request for the unit tests along with the new implementation, but sometimes I don't have the time (or authority, or expertise) to do so.

Is there an appropriate way to contribute these tests without fixing the broken functions? [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) will reject builds that fail tests – even though what was introduced only points out that the existing code is broken. What could repository owners do to correct such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to not merge these test to master. You should leave them on a separate branch where they will wait for the fix that makes them pass. Then both, fix and tests, can be merged to master without breaking a build.

Alternative you could just comment these tests or mark them as skipped/ignored. But it is actually a committing a dead code to your repository, so unless you have a good reason to do this, I would recommend to keep them on a separate branch.